# Can you hoard a Wild or Wild +4?

Tags: uno

Say you have a Wild card, and a blue 7, suddenly a person places a green 9. Technically, you have a playable card (the Wild), but you want to save it for your last card for a guaranteed win.

Are you allowed to save the Wild card even though it’s playable, instead drawing from the pile for a different playable card?

Answer (score 11):

In short, yes; it's called "reneging".

Here's a snippet from [the PDF of Uno's rules from Mattel's service website](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf).

[image: Snippet on "reneging" from a PDF of Uno's Rules.]

Comment: That seems like a strange way to use the word reneging.  I've always heard it used to indicate that someone didn't follow the rules and has to backtrack to correct the play.  I wouldn't call this reneging if the rules explicitly allow it.